# Firebase onCall function headers and parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Can someone tell me how I should start with a Firebase `onCall` function? according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) there is a protocol of headers and parameters that I have to include, where should I include them?. I am working from my localhost with Emulators.

I try something as simple as this:

```
export const getFileInformation2 = functions.https.onCall( (data, context) => {
  return { msg: 'Hello from Firebase!' };
});
```

Then I run:

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

So it generates the following url:

```
http://localhost:5001/[myProjectName]/us-central1/getFileInformation2
```

but it throws error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, developers do not concern themselves with URLs and headers when dealing with callable functions.  They just use the provided SDK to invoke the function without having to know those implementation details.  If you don't intend to use the provided SDK, then you probably don't want a callable function at all.

Comment: @Pacos Zevallos Could you post your solution as an answer so that other's could spot the workaround easier?

Answer (score 0):

`onCall` is meant for when you are using the client SDKs for firebase [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).  If you are calling a url using curl or any non-sdk client use the `onRequest` [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)

If you want to use on call, a good example on using the client sdk can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function)

Comment: Thanks @Nabel I need to use `onCall` since I want to call the function from my app (on the frontend). What I don't understand is why I get the error, am I missing something?

Comment: You can call normal HTTP endpoints from your app as well.  onCall just makes it easier to do so, but it's expected you use the client SDK and not invoke the function directly with a URL.  If you want to access the endpoint URL directly using some other SDK or procedure, then maybe you don't really want onCall at all.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson for the explanation, I was able to call and get the data like this: `getInfo() {
    const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);

    const getInfo = httpsCallable(functions, 'getFileInformation2')
    getInfo().then( (result) => {
      console.log(result.data);
    })
  }`